# Spinning Gears : Not responding after Reset Phone

Tags: 8.0, reset, spinning-gears

I tried a reset option in my phone and it asked for the permission and restarted. From then phone showing two gears spinning. It's still there for last 15 hours. I tried all known reset methods with keys. But it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokia [recently](http://www.wpcentral.com/suffering-spinning-cogs-issue-nokia-windows-phone-fix) released  their [NSU for Retail](http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fds_fire/1310/0909/7297834135/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.1.0.exe) tool. Follow the instructions at [WPCentral's guide](http://www.wpcentral.com/suffering-spinning-cogs-issue-nokia-windows-phone-fix), it's a fairly automated process. I had a phone (Lumia 920) that was bricked for two months that was fixed by this approach.